# IE PrintTemplate mixed context warning

Tags: internet-explorer, ssl, layout, printing, activex

I use the IE PrintTemplate to add custom page header/footer.
The print template sample I found in [Beyond Print Preview: Print Customization for Internet Explorer 5.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250434(VS.85).aspx).
But over SSL when the bowser renders following tag

```
<IE:LAYOUTRECT ID='layoutrect1' CONTENTSRC='document' ONLAYOUTCOMPLETE='OnRectComplete()' NEXTRECT='layoutrect2' CLASS='lorstyle'/>
```

The mixed context warning appers:

> This page contains both secure and nonsecure items.
>   Do you want to display the nonsecure items?

When I changed The context CONTENTSRC to direct URL the warning message disappeared. But the other strange issues are arisen.

```
<IE:LAYOUTRECT ID='layoutrect1' CONTENTSRC='https://..' ONLAYOUTCOMPLETE='OnRectComplete()' NEXTRECT='layoutrect2' CLASS='lorstyle'/>
```

Is it possible to mark the document that the ActiveX(WebConrol2) control contains as secure(avoid the mixed content warning)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just want to share the solution I found.

The IE behavior describe in question is applicable only for Internet Explorer 7.
The IE shows mixed context warning if the print template are loaded **via URL** (event it was transported via SSL).

If you use local print template **no warning appears**. 
So I imported print template as resource to ActiveX control and accessed it via the [res protocol](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/embedwin32resources.aspx).